# MariaDB unable to import this dump file

Tags: mariadb

I have MariaDB version 5.5.39

```
mysqldump -u root -p database > dumpfile.sql
```

Yes this is working fine; it produces a dump file.

But I am not able to import this dump file. All these commands are not working:

```
mysqldump -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql

mysqlimport -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql

mysql -u root -p database < dumpfile.sql
```

Can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -p --database=db_name < dumpfile.sql
```