# MYSQLDUMP : Errors while restoring database

Tags: mysql, importerror

I created a backup of mysql database from my live site using `mysqldump` and downloaded the SQL file (~960MB). I've a local install of MariaDB and I tried importing the database again using `mysqldump`. I am getting following error:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.16  Distrib 10.2.10-MariaDB, for osx10.13 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: original
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   10.2.10-MariaDB

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, 
FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;

-- Dump completed on 2017-12-01  8:27:08
```

I'm not allowed to make any changes to the live DB and would really appreciate if there's a way to import this DB successfully to my local DB.

Thank you in advance for your cooperation.

Comment: That's not an error, it's just comments in the dump file.

Comment: You don't use `mysqldump` to import, only to export. You use `mysql < filename` to import.

Comment: @Barmar - are you sure those aren't errors? Because the database didn't get imported.

Comment: Look at any file created by mysqldump, they all begin like that. They're special comments that are used to control database settings when you're importing.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in comments,

> That's not an error, it's just comments in the dump file.

Additionally,

> You don't use `mysqldump` to import, only to export. You use `mysql < filename` to import

From this question: [MariaDB i am not able to import this dump file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26729508/2194007)

You import the dump like so:

```
mysql -u root -p --database=db_name < dumpfile.sql
```